# Entity framework generic insert function and many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a generic method like below

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
    using (EntityUsers entityUser = new EntityUsers())
    {
         entityUser.Set<T>().Add(entity);
         entityUser.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There are three tables in my database. Users, Roles and UserRoles. UserRoles contains UserId and RoleId (many to many relationship). I add a new User to database with an existing Role using code below.

```
Entity.DAL.RepositoryUsers<User> UserDAL;
Entity.DAL.RepositoryUsers<Role> RoleDAL;

public ActionResult InsertUser(User user, int RoleId)
{
    RoleDAL = new Entity.DAL.RepositoryUsers<Role>();
    UserDAL = new Entity.DAL.RepositoryUsers<User>();

    Role role = RoleDAL.FindById(RoleId);
    user.Roles.Add(role);
    UserDAL.Add(user);
    return View(RoleDAL.FindAll().ToList());
}
```

My UserDAL.Add method adds a new role to Roles table. However I want to add a new user and its role to the UserRoles table. I am stucked on what is wrong with my code. How can I perform this?

Comment: IIRC you need to call `entityUser.Roles.Attach(user.Roles.Single())`. For this to work, you need to make `Add` non generic and accept a `User`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean that generic is not possible in this situation doesn't you? So I will update code like you suggest or I will find another solution.

Comment: it is possible, just make sure to attach it to the current context, if it comes from a different context

Comment: How can I attach if I do not know the type of the object?